# PHP post using ajax and appending response inside DIV

Tags: php, jquery

I'm playing around with Ajax, jQuery and PHP in an attempt to get familiar with the combination of them and how they integrate with each other. Here's my 1st attempt, it's a very simple form submission that does nothing special, just trying to see how ajax handles requests and responses.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">
    <title>My 1st AJAX attempt</title>
    <link href="http://www.ht-webcreations.com/test/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#wait').hide();

        $("#emailContactus").submit(function(){
             $('#wait').show(),
             $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                url: 'includes/ajax.php?action=emailContactus',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Success posting emailContactus"),
                    $('#wait').hide(),
                    $('#notifications').html(data).addClass('ajaxsuccess').show();
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Success posting emailContactus: "+ textStatus, errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function(data){
                    $('#wait').hide(),
                    $('#notifications').html(data).addClass('ajaxsuccess').show();
                }
            });
           return false;
         }); 
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wait"><img src="http://www.ht-webcreations.com/test/loading_ajax.gif" width="80" height="80"></div>
    <div id="notifications"></div>

    <form name="emailContactus" id="emailContactus" method="post">
      <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td><label for="name"></label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

ajax.php:

```
<?
/////////////////  AJAX REQUESTS  /////////////////
switch($_REQUEST['action']){
    case('emailContactus'): if($_POST['name']=='a') { echo $value = 'User is A'; } else { echo $value = 'User is NOT A'; } 
                                break;
    case('addContact'):         echo 'Contact added!'; 
                                break;
    default:                    break;

}
?>
```

**The problem** in this simple example [(working demo here)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dZLwId) is that though I expect the data response to be appended to the #notifications div, instead it's being outputted to the very top of the document, even before any HTML has been loaded. Please have a look and suggest what needs to be changed. Also, I will be glad to hear all your comments on my code as I would like to be pointed to the right direction from the start. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to hide the notifications div on page load, same wait you're doing with #wait

Comment: The problem is probably in your `includes/ajax.php` page. It's probably returning an entire HTML page rather than a partial one.

Comment: @jeremyharris is right, your ajax page should not contain any HTML in it. Only the php that produces the results.

Comment: I've edited my original code to make it more clear to all of you. ajax.php has only the code that I've added at the bottom of my code (the switch part). No html is included. I thought I'd keep all the ajax-related php code in one file, is that a wrong practice?

Comment: echo $value = 'User is A'; is invalid. You should not have a $var = in an echo statement. Should just be echo 'User is A';

Comment: If i don't echo it, I get TypeError: data is null

Comment: Try - if($_POST['name']=='a') { $value = 'User is A'; } else { $value = 'User is NOT A'; } echo $value;